# How to get all row id then pass them in a javascript function in bootstrap TbGridview?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I like to know how i can get all the row id then pass them in a JS function

Here is my code,

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'id'=>'salesman-track-points-grid',
'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
'dataProvider'=>$model,
    'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
    'enablePagination'=>true,
    'pagerCssClass'=>'pagination pagination-centered',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'cursor: pointer;'),
    'selectableRows'=>1,
    'selectionChanged'=>'trackPointClicks',
'columns'=>array(

        array(
            'name'=>'date',
            'header'=>'Date',
            'value'=>'$data["date"]',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'font-size:13px')
            ),
        array(
            'name'=>'time',
            'header'=>'Time',
            'value'=>'$data["time"]',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'font-size:13px')
            ),
),
```

));

I'll wait for your reply
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can show a link with custom attribute of your id for example and catch it with javascript

Answer (score 1):

if you want to id to js function through data column, you can pass it in htmloptions array

```
     array(
            'name'=>'date',
            'header'=>'Date',
            'value'=>'$data["date"]',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'font-size:13px','onclick'=>'your_js_function_name($data["date"])')
            ),
```